# Can you start Windows Search Service in Index Snoozing mode?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-search

I am using Windows Search on Windows XP, I would like it to start-up in "Index Snoozing" mode.  Is there an argument I can pass to the WindowsSearch service to enable that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you wanted but you try

Run "services.msc"

Set the "Windows Search service to "Manual" t

Then Click "Stop" on the "General" tab.